# Python equivalent of MATLAB's "ismember" function

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, numpy

After many attempts trying optimize code, it seems that one last resource would be to attempt to run the code below using multiple cores. I don't know exactly how to convert/re-structure my code so that it can run much faster using multiple cores. I will appreciate if I could get guidance to achieve the end goal. The end goal is to be able to run this code as fast as possible for arrays A and B where each array holds about 700,000 elements. Here is the code using small arrays.  The 700k element arrays are commented out.

```
import numpy as np

def ismember(a,b):
    for i in a:
        index = np.where(b==i)[0]
        if index.size == 0:
            yield 0
        else:
            yield index


def f(A, gen_obj):
    my_array = np.arange(len(A))
    for i in my_array:
        my_array[i] = gen_obj.next()
    return my_array


#A = np.arange(700000)
#B = np.arange(700000)
A = np.array([3,4,4,3,6])
B = np.array([2,5,2,6,3])

gen_obj = ismember(A,B)

f(A, gen_obj)

print 'done'
# if we print f(A, gen_obj) the output will be: [4 0 0 4 3]
# notice that the output array needs to be kept the same size as array A.
```

What I am trying to do is to mimic a MATLAB function called [ismember](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)[2] (The one that is formatted as: `[Lia,Locb] = ismember(A,B)`.  I am just trying to get the `Locb` part only.

> From Matlab: Locb, contain the lowest index in B for each value in A that is a member of B. The output array, Locb, contains 0 wherever A is not a member of B

One of the main problems is that I need to be able to perform this operation as efficient as possible.  For testing I have two arrays of 700k elements.  Creating a generator and going through the values of the generator doesn't seem to get the job done fast.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Before worrying about multiple cores, I would eliminate the linear scan in your ismember function by using a dictionary:

```
def ismember(a, b):
    bind = {}
    for i, elt in enumerate(b):
        if elt not in bind:
            bind[elt] = i
    return [bind.get(itm, None) for itm in a]  # None can be replaced by any other "not in b" value
```

Your original implementation requires a full scan of the elements in B for each element in A, making it `O(len(A)*len(B))`.  The above code requires one full scan of B to generate the dict Bset.  By using a dict, you effectively make the lookup of each element in B constant for each element of A, making the operation `O(len(A)+len(B))`.  If this is still too slow, then worry about making the above function run on multiple cores.

Edit: I've also modified your indexing slightly.  Matlab uses 0 because all of its arrays start at index 1.  Python/numpy start arrays at 0, so if you're data set looks like this

```
A = [2378, 2378, 2378, 2378]
B = [2378, 2379]
```

and you return 0 for no element, then your results will exclude all elements of A.  The above routine returns `None` for no index instead of 0.  Returning -1 is an option, but Python will interpret that to be the last element in the array.  `None` will raise an exception if it's used as an index into the array.  If you'd like different behavior, change the second argument in the `Bind.get(item,None)` expression to the value you want returned.

Comment: Wow this is really fast ! You have no idea how much I appreciate your solution.  Thank you very much !  Do you use a particular tool to output a performance profile ?

Comment: @z5151 No, it's straightforward algorithmic analysis.  Using [Big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation): `np.where` has to perform a linear scan of `B`, which requires `O(len(B))` operations.  You then use an outer loop that requires `O(len(A))` operations, making your original algorithm roughly `O(len(A)*len(B))` operations.  Generating `Bind` requires `len(B)` operations.  Dictionaries are implemented as [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), which have constant `O(1)` lookup, so scanning A is `O(len(A))`; the overall complexity is `O(len(A)+len(B))`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the wikipedia reference.

Comment: @z5151 I've changed the answer to try and alleviate a possible problem with your indexing.  Matlab uses 0 because all of its arrays start at index 1.  Python/numpy start arrays at 0, so an index of zero is a valid element.  The `ismember` function above now returns `None` if the element does not exist in the list.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your emphasis on comparing both Matlab and Python.

Comment: I vastly simplified the code. It should also run faster, as a consequence. I also followed the PEP 8 style recommandations.

Comment: @EOL No, you broke the code.  The element returned is now the **last** occurrence in the list, not the first.  There's a reason that I didn't use a dictionary comprehension in the original code.

Comment: @EOL As far as I can tell, you can use a dictionary comprehension by either iterating over the reversed range: `{ B[i] : i for i in xrange(len(B)-1,-1,-1) }`. Or by using a reverse iterator: `{ elt : len(B)-i-1) for (i,elt) in enumerate(reversed(B)) }`  Neither one is pretty (or simple).  The first assumes that B is indexable, and the second that B is reversible.  They also assume that random index/reverse iteration are cheap.  If B is a very large linked list, your performance will be abysmal.  Is there a method of using a comprehension to retrieve the first index that only assumes iteration?

Comment: @sfstewman: You are right, about the *first* occurrence being required (I thought it did not matter). Since in the question `B` is a NumPy array, both of the dictionary comprehensions that you give work. `reversed()` is even efficient since it gives an iterator. Timing the three approaches would tell us which one is the fastest (`len(B)-1` should probably be precomputed, in the `reversed()` approach).

Comment: PS: I did modify your code and applied PEP 8 guidelines, though. I also simplified the `if bind.get(elt) is None` as the standard, more explicit and faster `if elt not in bind` (which does not force the reader to know that `None` is not a possible dictionary value).

Comment: Amazing... this should be part of the numpy implementation!

Answer (score 15):

sfstewman's excellent answer most likely solved the issue for you.

I'd just like to add how you can achieve the same exclusively in numpy.

I make use of numpy's [unique](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy.unique) an [in1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html#numpy.in1d) functions.

```
B_unique_sorted, B_idx = np.unique(B, return_index=True)
B_in_A_bool = np.in1d(B_unique_sorted, A, assume_unique=True)
```

- `B_unique_sorted` contains the unique values in `B` sorted.
- `B_idx` holds for these values the indices into the original `B`.
- `B_in_A_bool` is a boolean array the size of `B_unique_sorted` that
  stores whether a value in `B_unique_sorted` is in `A`.
  **Note:** I need to look for *(unique vals from B) in A* because I need the output to be returned with respect to `B_idx`
  **Note:** I assume that `A` is already unique.

Now you can use `B_in_A_bool` to either get the common vals

```
B_unique_sorted[B_in_A_bool]
```

and their respective indices in the original `B`

```
B_idx[B_in_A_bool]
```

Finally, I assume that this is significantly faster than the pure Python for-loop although I didn't test it.

Comment: +1 for just using numpy wherever possible, major speedups can be achieved this way (as I have learned the hard way >_<)

Comment: Watch out! This does not preserve the order of the indices! try it with range(1,6) and [5,1]. In case the order of the indices is not need I think you can just use np.in1d() and then np.nonzero()[0]

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678543/finding-indices-of-matches-of-one-array-in-another-array for getting indices in the right order

Answer (score 2):

Try the `ismember` library.

```
pip install ismember
```

Simple example:

```
# Import library
from ismember import ismember
import numpy as np

# data
A = np.array([3,4,4,3,6])
B = np.array([2,5,2,6,3])

# Lookup
Iloc,idx = ismember(A, B)
 
# Iloc is boolean defining existence of d in d_unique
print(Iloc)
# [ True False False  True  True]

# indexes of d_unique that exists in d
print(idx)
# [4 4 3]

print(B[idx])
# [3 3 6]

print(A[Iloc])
# [3 3 6]

# These vectors will match
A[Iloc]==B[idx]
```

Speed check:

```
from ismember import ismember
from datetime import datetime

t1=[]
t2=[]
# Create some random vectors
ns = np.random.randint(10,10000,1000)

for n in ns:
    a_vec = np.random.randint(0,100,n)
    b_vec = np.random.randint(0,100,n)

    # Run stack version
    start = datetime.now()
    out1=ismember_stack(a_vec, b_vec)
    end = datetime.now()
    t1.append(end - start)

    # Run ismember
    start = datetime.now()
    out2=ismember(a_vec, b_vec)
    end = datetime.now()
    t2.append(end - start)


print(np.sum(t1))
# 0:00:07.778331

print(np.sum(t2))
# 0:00:04.609801

# %%
def ismember_stack(a, b):
    bind = {}
    for i, elt in enumerate(b):
        if elt not in bind:
            bind[elt] = i
    return [bind.get(itm, None) for itm in a]  # None can be replaced by any other "not in b" value
```

The `ismember` function from pypi is almost 2x faster.

Large vectors, eg 700000 elements:

```
from ismember import ismember
from datetime import datetime

A = np.random.randint(0,100,700000)
B = np.random.randint(0,100,700000)

# Lookup
start = datetime.now()
Iloc,idx = ismember(A, B)
end = datetime.now()

# Print time
print(end-start)
# 0:00:01.194801
```

Comment: @EOL What do you think of this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a list comprehension;

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([3,4,4,3,6])

In [3]: B = np.array([2,5,2,6,3])

In [4]: [x for x in A if not x in B]
Out[4]: [4, 4]
```

Generally, list comprehensions are much faster than for-loops.

To get an equal length-list;

```
In [19]: map(lambda x: x if x not in B else False, A)
Out[19]: [False, 4, 4, False, False]
```

This is quite fast for small datasets:

```
In [20]: C = np.arange(10000)

In [21]: D = np.arange(15000, 25000)

In [22]: %timeit map(lambda x: x if x not in D else False, C)
1 loops, best of 3: 756 ms per loop
```

For large datasets, you could try using a `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` to speed up the operation.

Comment: The output array needs to be kept the same size.

Comment: @z5151: See enhanced answer. You can change the `lambda` expression to return 0 instead of False if you want, but that would mask real 0's in the results.

Comment: This is useful for arrays with small number of elements. Thank you for emphasizing  that list comprehensions are much faster than loops.

Comment: Your answer returns the elements, not the index of the elements in B.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the exact MATLAB equivalent that returns both the output arguments [Lia, Locb] that match MATLAB except in Python 0 is also a valid index. So, this function doesn't return the 0s. It essentially returns Locb(Locb>0). The performance is also equivalent to MATLAB.

```
def ismember(a_vec, b_vec):
    """ MATLAB equivalent ismember function """

    bool_ind = np.isin(a_vec,b_vec)
    common = a[bool_ind]
    common_unique, common_inv  = np.unique(common, return_inverse=True)     # common = common_unique[common_inv]
    b_unique, b_ind = np.unique(b_vec, return_index=True)  # b_unique = b_vec[b_ind]
    common_ind = b_ind[np.isin(b_unique, common_unique, assume_unique=True)]
    return bool_ind, common_ind[common_inv]
```

An alternate implementation that is a bit (~5x) slower but doesn't use the unique function is here:

```
def ismember(a_vec, b_vec):
    ''' MATLAB equivalent ismember function. Slower than above implementation'''
    b_dict = {b_vec[i]: i for i in range(0, len(b_vec))}
    indices = [b_dict.get(x) for x in a_vec if b_dict.get(x) is not None]
    booleans = np.in1d(a_vec, b_vec)
    return booleans, np.array(indices, dtype=int)
```