# How to implement matlab's ismember(A, b) with A being a numpy ndarray and b being a list

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, list, numpy

What is the most efficient way to implement matlab's [ismember(A, b)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) in python where in A is any numpy ndarray and b is a list of values. It should return a mask as a boolean ndarray of the same shape as A where in an element is True if the corresponding value in A is in the list of values in b.

I want to replace all elements of A with value in list B with something.

I expected `A[A in B] = 0` to work but it throws the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

If an implementation of an equivalent of `ismember` is there then the following would do what I need:

```
A[ismember(A, b)] = 0
```

Note: I don't want solutions involving looping through all elements of A in python.

Based on the answer of [ajcr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923281/ajcr), one solution is:

```
import numpy as np

def ismember(A, b):
  return np.in1d(A, b).reshape(A.shape)
```

But this is quite slow and runs out of memory. For my case, A is an image as big as 512 x 512 x 1200. b has about 1000 elements.

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
>>> A = np.arange(9)
>>> B = [4, 6, 7]
>>> np.in1d(A, B)
array([False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Note that for multidimensional arrays `A`, the input is flattened so you'll need to reshape the boolean array:

```
>>> A = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> np.in1d(A, B).reshape(A.shape)
array([[False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks! Paralelly i arrived at def ismember(A, b): return np.in1d(A.flatten(), b).reshape(A.shape)

Comment: It is very slow and runs out of memory for A of size 512 x 512 x 1200 and b of size 3800. I see some sorting going on inside [in1d](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L296)

Comment: I think that's one of the inevitabilities of working with very large NumPy arrays - there isn't an obvious solution to this problem which avoids looping over the array. If memory is a problem, you could consider trying other non-NumPy data structures or using memory-mapped arrays...

Answer (score 0):

The `ismember` library in pypi may be useful.

Speed check is done here: [Python equivalent of MATLAB's "ismember" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864082/python-equivalent-of-matlabs-ismember-function/62504972#62504972)

```
pip install ismember
```

Comment: If you find that a question is answered by an answer elsewhere, don’t post an answer linking the other question. Instead, flag the question to be closed as duplicate.