# check membership of a set in python

Tags: python, numpy

I had a statement in my python code something like

```
msk = (var1 == 49) | (var1 == 26) | (var1 == 28)
```

Now, instead of (49,26,28), I want to have a longer list, and want to make it variable,

I tried the solution at
[Python equivalent of MATLAB's "ismember" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864082/python-equivalent-of-matlabs-ismember-function)
but it is not exactly what I want.

Something like:

```
msk = (var1 == list1)
```

Comment: What is `|` in this context? For Python `set` operations, `|` stands for `set` union.

Comment: `if 49 in set or 26 in set or 28 in set:`

Comment: Closing as duplicate of the linked question in the post, as one of the answers to it has already mentioned use of `np.in1d`.

Comment: Python set membership can be checked with the `in` operator.  For example with `my_set = set([1, 2, 3])` use `[i in my_set for i in [2, 4]]`.  However from the context of the question, I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for is what the title says.

Comment: I'd go with `if your_set.union(your_list) == your_set:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator:

```
msk = var1 in {49, 26, 28}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [set intersection operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
import numpy as np

list1 = np.Array([1, 2, 3, 49])
list2 = np.Array([1, 2, 3, 4])

msk1 = any({49, 26, 28} & set(list1))
# => True

msk2 = any({49, 26, 28} & set(list2))
# => False
```

This works for both numpy arrays and regular lists.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) should work for this case:

```
a
Out[153]: array([ 1, 10, 26, 28, 40, 49])

b
Out[154]: array([26, 28, 49, 50])
```

To check whether an element in array a is also in array b:

```
np.in1d(a, b)
Out[156]: array([False, False,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Of course you can use it for single elements as well:

```
np.in1d(28, b)
Out[158]: array([ True], dtype=bool)

np.in1d(43, b)
Out[159]: array([False], dtype=bool)
```