# Placing values of a smaller list at appropriate places in a larger list

Tags: python, indexing

I need to enter the values of a smaller list at appropriate locations in a larger list, e.g.,

```
l_1 = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
v_1 = [5, 6, 8, 10]

l_2 = ['a', 'ab', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I am looking to generate a `v_2` of values (initialized as zeros of size `l_2`) which takes `v_1` at locations where `l_1` belongs to `l_2`. So, for the above example, I would like to get

```
v_2 = [5, 0, 6, 10, 8]
```

Clearly, `l_1` is a subset of `l_2`, i.e., `l_2` will always have the quantities of `l_1`.

I found the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864082/python-equivalent-of-matlabs-ismember-function/15864429) helpful to determine the location of `l_1` in `l_2` and am looking to modify it to suit my case. Ideally, I would like to have 3 inputs

```
a = l_1
b = l_2 
val = v_1

def ismember(a, b, val):
    bind = {}
    for i, elt in enumerate(b):
        if elt not in bind:
            bind[elt] = i
    return [bind.get(itm, None) for itm in a]
```

And I need to get the return statement modified so that appropriate entries of `v_1` are entered into the padded `v_2`, which, can be initialized as `np.zeros((len(b),1))` within the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to construct a `dict` for lookups using the values from `l_1` as keys and `v_1` as values. For example:

```
>>> l_1 = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'd']
>>> v_1 = [5, 6, 8, 10]
>>> l_2 = ['a', 'ab', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

then

```
>>> d = dict(zip(l_1, v_1))
>>> [d.get(i, 0) for i in l_2]
[5, 0, 6, 10, 8]
```